# Suppress Compiler Warnings in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I'm trying to clear the warnings given when my solution compiles in VS2010. Currently there are some 600, but most seem to be due to MSpec files.

How can I suppress the warnings for any file that ends *spec.cs? They're for MSpec tests and fixing many of them break the flow of the test code. I'm sure I won't need to consider those when the product is shipped.

Comment: Fix the cause of the warnings.

Answer (score 9):

In C# go to Project >  Properties Alt+F7 > Build page > Errors and warnings section > Suppress warnings text box. Enter numbers of the warnings separated by comma or semicolon.

In C++ go to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Disable Specific Warnings text box. Enter numbers of the warnings separated by semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to only disable warnings for specific files. The warnings are valid when they're outside the MSpec test files.

Comment: I don't think you can do it for specific files in C#. There are no two separate building phases like in C++. All .cs files are built together with one single action. You could try to build all warning-intense code into separate dll. Then the rest of the code would be warning-free.

Answer (score 7):

At the top of the file put:

```
#pragma warning disable
```

---

Or for a specific warning: (for example warning CS0649)

```
#pragma warning disable 649
```